# html unescape does not always work as expected

Tags: python, html, json, character-encoding

with python I am requesting an HTML website. After responding and extracting a JSON file it will be loaded with `json_data = json.loads(page_data)`. I will navigate to the right elements and loop over an array. An array example is shown below:

```
[{
    "name": "Ziaja - K\u00f6rperpeeling - Jeju - Black Micro Srub &amp; Body Wash",
    "id": "ZI277",
    "price": 5.95,
    "brand": "Ziaja",
    "category": "K\u00f6rperpeeling",
    "list": "Category",
    "position": 16
}]
```

Now the `name` element has to be converted.

```
for element in json_data:
    name = html.unescape(name) # TODO: replace is not always working
    print("{} -> {}".format(old_name, name))
```

By executing the code above the following output is generated:

```
Ziaja - Ku00f6rperpeeling - Jeju - Black Micro Srub &amp; Body Wash -> Ziaja - Ku00f6rperpeeling - Jeju - Black Micro Srub & Body Wash
```

Searching through the history of all elements shows that some umlauts are converted fine.

Using the console will output the following:

```
>>> l = "Ziaja - K\u00f6rperpeeling - Jeju - Black Micro Srub &amp; Body Wash"
>>> import html
>>> html.unescape(l)
'Ziaja - Körperpeeling - Jeju - Black Micro Srub & Body Wash'
```

Whats wrong with my code? Is the problem connected with encoding?

Comment: Why not save in utf8 and thus have `körperpeeling` instead of `\u00f6`  - also it is `Scrub` and not `Srup`

Comment: @mplungjan It's not possible because i will get the array from an 3rd party webservice. We can't modify it.

Comment: Please [edit] the question. A [mcve] would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `r"K\u00f6rperpeeling".encode().decode('unicode-escape')` returns `Körperpeeling`…